# Pagination with manual entry of page number

Tags: javascript, css, angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to search for pagination with manual entry of page number.
I tried to use ngb-pagination and it is working great until I had a requirement for the user that he should be able to enter the page number manually to navigate to the desired page.

I was able to achieve it by JavaScript.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nconlz. But it seems quite odd with adding manual entry.

Use case: User should be able to navigate page by page and also he should be able to manually enter the page number like below;

[image]

I would rather not stick to ngb-pagination only, if you anyone could let me know any pagination of above kind is deeply appreciated.

PS: I am avoiding jquery and jquery plugins.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, from a brief review of "ngx-paginationdocumentation"  I see that you can customize the style to show what you want

Comment: I am using ngb-paingation, haven't gone through ngx-pagination